# gcloud logs on CLI using timestamp filter

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, gcloud, stackdriver

I am trying to get logs from gcloud(GKE) to count the number of different HTTP error codes.. here is my command:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=container AND resource.labels.cluster_name=AAA AND resource.labels.namespace_id=BBB AND timestamp>=(2018-09-21T13:20:00Z) AND timestamp<=(2018-09-21T13:30:00Z)" |grep -i textpayload -A 1| grep 'GET\|POST\|PUT\|DELETE\|HEAD' | grep -v null | awk '{print $9}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

If I remove the "timestamp" and use "--limit" it gives me output and everything is fine but I want to get logs for a particular period and as per documentation I should use "timestamp" filter but this is giving me following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter:
>   syntax error at line 1, column 155, token ':'; syntax error at line 1,
>   column 193, token ':'

Please help me with correct syntax of specifying timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the timestamp strings (and all the other string values within your filter string).

I know! It's not my favorite either but...

`gcloud logging read "timestamp>=\"2018-09-21T13:20:00Z\" AND timestamp<=\"2018-09-21T13:30:00Z\""`

Comment: Thanks Daz. Escaping the quotes and other special characters made it run.

Comment: if you use single quotes, you don't need to backslash the double quotes.  e.g.

gcloud logging read 'timestamp>="2018-09-21T13:20:00Z" AND timestamp<="2018-09-21T13:30:00Z"'

Comment: That's true but double quotes enables variable substitution too which is convenient

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your syntax seems to be incorrect. I was able to successfully read logs entries using the following commands(you can find [examples](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) of using this command):

> gcloud logging read \
>         'resource.type=container AND resource.labels.cluster_name=standard-cluster-2 AND
>   timestamp<="2018-09-21T23:59:59Z" AND
>   timestamp>="2018-09-21T00:00:00Z"' --limit=2